# Auth0 integration with NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx, auth0

I wanted to have ngrx with Auth0. Also found nice tutorial here: https://auth0.com/blog/ngrx-authentication-tutorial/ . The problem is after redirection to login modal and going back to my app I am loosing app state, so it seems like app was restarted.

Do you know what can I do?

Also is it worth to use ngrx+auth0?

Answer (score 0):

After the successful authentication you probably need to store the token into the localstorage/session-storage, then when you app "restart" you can check  for the access-token previously saved, make a request with that in order to grab the user info and save them into the state.

If you're integrating with an OAuth provider I suggest to give a look to [this library](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client)

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch your action and check the state in your route guard. That way you always check the state and update if its empty for any authorised route.

- `checkLogin` - this will check if the user is authenticated. If they are, get the user profile and any other logic (localstorage, memory, etc for your state), if they arent then redirect to login.
- `selectIsAuthenticated` - boolean from the auth state which is set through the above check.

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(
        private store: Store<AppStore>
    ) { }

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        this.store.dispatch(checkLogin());
        return this.store.select(selectIsAuthenticated);
    }
}
```